# scrape responsive table from site whose url doesnt change

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want price history scraped from this site: upon click of price history button the table gets loaded but the url remains same. I want to scrape the table loaded.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
rr = requests.get(url)
htmll = rr.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmll)
```

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to load data. If you use DevTools (tab `Network`) in Chrome/Firefox then you see it loads table from `https://www.sharesansar.com/company-price-history?draw=....` and you may try to use this url to get table. It get it as JSON data so you will no need `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 2):

Using `DevTools` (tab: `Network`) in Chrome/Firefox you can see this page uses `JavaScript` to load data from another URL.

```
https://www.sharesansar.com/company-price-history?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=DT_Row_Index&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=published_date&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=open&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=high&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=low&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=close&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=per_change&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=traded_quantity&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=traded_amount&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&start=0&length=20&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&company=95&_=1639245456705'
```

Using `requests` with this url you can get table as JSON data and you don't need `BeautifulSoup`

---

In code I converted all values from this url to `payload` - so you can easy replace values to get different data.

Probably if you change `'start'` (`20`, `40`, etc.) then you can get next pages in table.

If  you use `'length": 50` then you get more values in one request - but bigger values doesn't work.

BTW: This url needs header `X-Requested-With` which is used by `AJAX` requests.

```
import requests

payload = {
 '_': '1639245456705',
 'columns[0][data]': 'DT_Row_Index',
 'columns[0][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[0][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[1][data]': 'published_date',
 'columns[1][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
 'columns[2][data]': 'open',
 'columns[2][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[2][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[3][data]': 'high',
 'columns[3][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[3][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[4][data]': 'low',
 'columns[4][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[4][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[4][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[5][data]': 'close',
 'columns[5][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[5][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[5][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[6][data]': 'per_change',
 'columns[6][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[6][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[6][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[7][data]': 'traded_quantity',
 'columns[7][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[7][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[7][searchable]': 'false',
 'columns[8][data]': 'traded_amount',
 'columns[8][orderable]': 'false',
 'columns[8][search][regex]': 'false',
 'columns[8][searchable]': 'false',
 'company': '95',
 'draw': '1',
 'length': '20',
 'search[regex]': 'false',
 'start': '0'
}

headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

url = 'https://www.sharesansar.com/company-price-history'

response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
data = response.json() 
#print(data)

print('NR  | DATA       | OPEN   | CLOSE  |')
for number, item in enumerate(data['data'], 1):
    print(f'{number:3} |', item['published_date'], "|", item['open'], "|", item['close'], "|")
```

Result:

```
NR  | DATA       | OPEN   | CLOSE  |
  1 | 2021-12-09 | 208.70 | 206.00 |
  2 | 2021-12-08 | 214.90 | 205.00 |
  3 | 2021-12-07 | 218.00 | 211.00 |
  4 | 2021-12-06 | 208.00 | 214.00 |
  5 | 2021-12-05 | 215.00 | 211.00 |
  6 | 2021-12-02 | 225.00 | 217.10 |
  7 | 2021-12-01 | 226.00 | 224.50 |
  8 | 2021-11-30 | 224.60 | 225.00 |
  9 | 2021-11-29 | 227.00 | 225.00 |
 10 | 2021-11-28 | 233.00 | 227.00 |
 11 | 2021-11-25 | 233.00 | 237.00 |
 12 | 2021-11-24 | 228.00 | 230.00 |
 13 | 2021-11-23 | 233.50 | 230.10 |
 14 | 2021-11-22 | 238.00 | 237.00 |
 15 | 2021-11-21 | 242.70 | 234.40 |
 16 | 2021-11-18 | 236.00 | 240.00 |
 17 | 2021-11-17 | 243.00 | 240.00 |
 18 | 2021-11-16 | 232.00 | 239.90 |
 19 | 2021-11-15 | 226.00 | 231.50 |
 20 | 2021-11-14 | 228.00 | 225.60 |
```