# Selenium: Next pages with javascript throwing ElementClickInterceptedException Error

Tags: python, selenium

My code is working fine but the `pagination portion` throwing the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: 
Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <a href="#cpricehistory" data-toggle="tab" class="pill-item" id="btn_cpricehistory" aria-expanded="true">...</a> 
is not clickable at point (165, 19). 
Other element would receive the click: <a href="#">...</a>
```

Your help is much appreciate

Script:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


url = 'https://www.sharesansar.com/company/shl'

cdm = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(cdm)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
data =[]

while True:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Price History').click()
    time.sleep(3)

    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@name="myTableCPriceHistory_length"]'))))
    select.select_by_visible_text("50")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')

    tables =soup.select('#myTableCPriceHistory tbody tr')

    for table in tables:
        _open = table.select_one('td:nth-child(3)').text
        high = table.select_one('td:nth-child(4)').text
        low = table.select_one('td:nth-child(5)').text
        close = table.select_one('td:nth-child(6)').text

        print ( f"""
        Opening:{_open}
        High:{high}
        Low:{low} 
        """)

    print("-" * 85)

    
    # next_page=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Next")]')
    # if next_page:
    #     next_page.click()
    #     time.sleep(3)
    # else:
    #     break
#while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"]/span/following-sibling::a'))).click()
        print("Clicked on  Next Page »")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("No more Next Page »")
        break
driver.quit()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: full error message shows problem with clicking again `'Price History'` but you don't need to click it again to get next page. You should click it only once - before `while`-loop. And the same with selecting `50` - you should select it only once - before `while`-loop.

Comment: yesteday was similar question and I show how to get it using `requests` instead of `Selenium`: [scrape responsive table from site whose url doesnt change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70317002/scrape-responsive-table-from-site-whose-url-doesnt-change/70317874#70317874)

Comment: `TimeoutException` is wrong idea because button `Next` exists also on last page and it will load again and again last page. You have to check if it has class `disabled` or use `'//a[@class="paginate_button next"]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full error message shows problem with clicking again `'Price History'` but you don't need to click it again to get next page. You should click it only once - before `while`-loop.

And the same with `selecting 50`. You should select it only once - before `while`-loop.

Other problem makes `Next Page` because it exists even on last page and it click again and again `Next Page` which load again and again last page.

Normally this button has class `"paginate_button next"` but on last page it has class `"paginate_button next disabled"` - so if you will search class `"paginate_button next"` then you should detect last page

```
'//a[@class="paginate_button next"]'
```

---

Full working code:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://www.sharesansar.com/company/shl'

cdm = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(cdm)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

data = []

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Price History').click()
time.sleep(3)

select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@name="myTableCPriceHistory_length"]'))))
select.select_by_visible_text("50")

while True:
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    tables = soup.select('#myTableCPriceHistory tbody tr')

    for table in tables:
        _open = table.select_one('td:nth-child(3)').text
        high = table.select_one('td:nth-child(4)').text
        low = table.select_one('td:nth-child(5)').text
        close = table.select_one('td:nth-child(6)').text

        print(f"Opening: {_open}\nHigh: {high}\nLow: {low}\n")

    print("-" * 85)
    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="paginate_button next"]'))).click()
        print("Clicked on Next Page »")
        time.sleep(5)  # page needs time to load new data
    except TimeoutException:
        print("No more Next Page »")
        break
        
driver.quit()
```

---

**BTW:**

Yesterday was similar question and I show how to get this table using only `requests` instead of `Selenium`. It gets JSON data directly from API so it doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`.

[scrape responsive table from site whose url doesnt change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70317002/scrape-responsive-table-from-site-whose-url-doesnt-change/70317874#70317874)